# using CASE in where clause with IN condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the below code which needs a case condition based on the parameter.. IS this achievable? how to use the sql for this type.. I dont see any varaiation method to do this without the case

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @INPUT AS VARCHAR(256)
set @input = 'NASS'
SELECT
sum(TRY_PARSE(DV.[ERSDataValues_AttributeValue1] as decimal)) AS NEWVALUE

FROM [VegetablesCoSD-Full].[CoSD].[ERSDataValues] DV LEFT JOIN [CoSD].        [ERSTimeDimension_LU] TD

ON DV.ERSDataValues_ERSTimeDimension_ID = TD.ERSTimeDimension_ID

WHERE DV.ERSDataValues_ERSStatisticType_ID1 = 45 AND 
DV.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID = 519 AND
DV.ERSDataValues_ERSGeography_ID = 3346 AND
DV.ERSDataValues_ERSUnit_ID1 = 89 AND         

TD.ERSTimeDimension_TimeDimensionType_ID = 11 and 
CASE  
when @INPUT = 'NASS' THEN
TD.ERSTimeDimension_Month in   

('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
WHEN @INPUT = 'BLS' THEN
TD.ERSTimeDimension_Month IN('JAN','FEB')
END
```

Comment: Is there any error when u run this??

Comment: No it doesnt have any error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `OR` instead, like this:

```
AND
(   (@INPUT = 'MASS' AND TD.ERSTimeDimension_Month in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'))
    OR
    (@INPUT = 'BLS' AND TD.ERSTimeDimension_Month IN('JAN','FEB')
)
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution